# Kotlin and Dagger2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm trying to add Kotlin to my project, but after enabling Kotlin I can't build as the Dagger2 classes no longer get generated. I tried a second project, and I have the same issue (it's actually worse, it complains about both Dagger2 and DataBinding).

These are the changes I have done to enable Kotlin:

Project build.gradle:

```
diff --git a/build.gradle b/build.gradle
index 486700c..91e4cda 100644
--- a/build.gradle
+++ b/build.gradle
@@ -1,13 +1,15 @@
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {
+    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.5-3'
     repositories {
         jcenter()
     }
     dependencies {
-        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-alpha2'
+        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta1'
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
         classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
+        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
         // in the individual module build.gradle files
```

App build.gradle:

```
diff --git a/app/build.gradle b/app/build.gradle
index 345dab0..e59f91c 100644
--- a/app/build.gradle
+++ b/app/build.gradle
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
-apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
+apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
+apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 25
@@ -39,6 +40,13 @@ android {
         incremental true
         javaMaxHeapSize "5g"
     }
+    sourceSets {
+        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
+    }
+}
+
+kapt {
+    generateStubs = true
 }

 dependencies {
@@ -71,11 +79,15 @@ dependencies {
     compile 'com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.2.1.0'

     // Dagger 2
-    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
-    testApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
+    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
+    //testApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
     compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
     provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
+    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
+repositories {
+    mavenCentral()
+}
```

The error happens here:

```
sObjectGraph = DaggerObjectGraph
    .builder()
    .appModule(new AppModule(context.getApplicationContext()))
    .build();
```

where DaggerObjectGraph is no longer defined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use `kotlin-kapt` explicitly. This is a wild guess though.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, but the info I found online for Dagger2 with Kotlin clearly indicates that the kapt processor needs to be used (https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/better-annotation-processing-supporting-stubs-in-kapt/).

Comment: Try without it.

Comment: I have managed to build by converting my Dagger2 components and modules to Kotlin, and then going through all injectable classes and converting them to Kotlin as well. While this works, it can't be the right solution as the whole idea about Kotlin is interoperability, and having to convert everything right off the bat to Kotlin so just I can compile is not right.
If I remove kapt I can't compile injectable Kotlin files.

Comment: My guess was wrong then, sorry. I figured the issue is with kapt2, but I guess not

Answer (score 2):

Just remove

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is your are using

> DaggerObjectGraph

which is no longer available in dagger2.

[Here is the documentation for dagger 2](https://google.github.io/dagger//users-guide.html).

This is a working version

in your app level build.gradle add the following under the dependencies closure

```
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9"
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

also add this to the same file

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Then create the components and module classes and inject in whatever activity or fragment that you want.

Here is a sample Component Class

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, NetModule::class))
interface AppComponent {

    fun gson() : Gson
    fun retrofit(): Retrofit
    fun okHttpClient(): OkHttpClient
}
```

Here is a sample Module class

```
@Module
class AppModule(internal var mApplication: Application) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesApplication(): Application {
        return mApplication
    }

}
```

In my application class

```
class App : Application() {

companion object {
    @JvmStatic lateinit var component: AppComponent
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(AppModule(this))
            .netModule(NetModule(Constants.BASE_URL))
            .build()

}


}
```

This is how dagger components are initialised in dagger 2. You can now create subcomponents for different activities or fragment and inject them.